# how to import greengrassdk in raspberry pi 4

Tags: aws-lambda

IM  installed aws green grass core software in my raspberry pi and i want to receive  my dht sensor data into iot green grass using lambda function, my dht sensor is connected with my raspberry.

so how  install greengrasssdk and import it into my lambda function?

I want to install it correctly